# Automorphism group of an abelian group abelian

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

Is the automorphism group of an abelian group abelian? If not is it true if either is finite?
I cannot come up with a proof or an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the automorphism group of $C_2\times C_2$ is isomorphic to the non-abelian group $S_3$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! What is $C_2$?

Comment: $C_2$ is the cyclic group with $2$ elements.

Comment: $C_n=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z=\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks a bunch!